# How to pause and resume game using the escape key?

Tags: java, multithreading

How do I make my Escape key pause and resume a game when it is pressed twice? I have tried calling the key adapter class in my thread class but it only pauses the game; it does not resume it.

Here is the code that pauses the game:

```
//the thread class
class recMove extends Thread {
    JFrame b;

    public boolean running=true;

    //public boolean gameover=false;
    public recMove(JFrame b){
        this.b=b;
        pauseGame();
    }

    public void run(){
        while(running){
            b.repaint();
            try {
               Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
   }

   public void pauseGame(){
       addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
           public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
              int keyCode=e.getKeyCode();
              if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                  running=false;
                  System.out.println("escape pressed");
              }
              if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_END){
                  System.exit(0);
              }
          }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Start by using an `AtomicBoolean` instead of a plain `boolean`.  You should also have a inner pause lock which will cause the main loop to wait within it until your resume the game, unless you intend to stop it. Maybe something like [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715950/control-of-running-thread-using-multiple-threading-concept-of-java/31716210#31716210)

Comment: thanks much, don't know much about that but I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't resume because the thread is killed, when you press escape the `running` value is set to `false` therefore this loop:

```
while(running){
    b.repaint();
    try {
       Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch(InterruptedException e){}
}
```

Will end, which in turn will make the `run()` method exit. When a `run()` method of a class extending `Thread` (or implementing `Runnable`) exits that thread is being killed so there's nothing more listening for your keypresses.

You need to change your `run()` logic so it doesn't exit when `running` is set to `false` but instead wait for the next keypress or add the listener somewhere else (in a different thread) so it will create a new thread with the game again.

Furthermore in your logic `esc` only changes `running` to false, if you want it to then resume the game you should check the state of `running` and if it's `false` you should set it to `true` instead.

Comment: Please can you also help me with this............http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776720/how-to-make-all-my-bullets-remove-intersected-objects